# How to input sokuon in Gboard's Japanese 12-key on Android phone?

Tags: gboard

I'm using Gboard's Japanese 12-key. I want to write っ, such a sign that is called "sokuon (促音)", but I don't know how to put it in the 12-key input method.

How to input sokuon in Gboard's Japanese 12-key on Android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write it normally:

1. Swipe up た to write つ
2. Press the 濁点 key which also includes 大⇔小 to convert it to a small っ

Alternatively:

1. Swipe up た to write つ
2. Choose っ（小書き） from the suggestion strip

Tips: Gboard also includes *dakuten* and *sokuon* as suggestions without needing to manually convert them. To write ピッツァ, writing ひつつあ may suggest ピッツァ.

Comment: Much thanks! I really appreciate your answer, especially for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You must long press on a key. You will then see the other keyboard keys (characters) being displayed. Select the characters you want to type by moving your finger up or down or left or right depending on the character.